# how to determine parent/child of the usb device in objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb, iokit

I'm working on a project working with usb devices that finding the parent/child of the usb device, i have deployed this on window platform with following information:

example:

> Device 
>   "USB\VID_1234&PID_5678\REV_9012"
>
> Parent
>   "IUSB3\ROOT_HUB30\4&3089b9df_0"
>
> Child
>   "HID\VID_ABCD&PID_EFGH\6&210a22d8\&0&8"

And i can read these USB device information by using IOKIT framework, and i am wondering whether has any functions for extracting these information on OS X? So far, hours of Googling has turned up nothing, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

thanks in advance,

regards

Comment: The strings you have there are Windows-specific strings for identifying USB devices.  Since IOKit runs on Mac OS X, it doesn't give you those strings, because those strings are specific to Windows.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Could [libusb](http://libusb.info) be a solution to your problem?  The first string you posted has the vendor ID, product ID, and firmware revision of the device; it should be possible to get that information in IOKit.  If you want to make your app portable, you probably should not rely on having strings like that available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOKit *is* the OS X method of accessing this information… the locationID fields give you the topology… zero'ng the least-siginfigant non-zero nibble will give you the parent's locationID (at least until you hit the USB controller).

Comment: Great answer, Im a little confused by "zero'ng the least-siginfigant non-zero nibble will give you the parent's locationID" can you add an example of doing it? thanks

Comment: If a devices location ID is 31415900 then it’s plugged into the 9th port of a hub with the location ID of 31415000. That hub is plugged into the 5th port of a hub with the location id of 31410000. That hub is plugged into the 1st port of a hub with the location ID of 31400000, etc. etc. etc.